# Why can't I connect to my access database

Tags: vbscript, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a Microsoft Access 2010 database that will be part of a small web site for a client. I've debugged it with message boxes and I'm able to accept the data with the VBScript (client's choice as they are willing to update/maintain the web site contents), I'm able to call the sub that sends the data to the database, but I can't get past the connection to the database. Here's what I have:

```
Sub InsertIntoDatabase(FullName)

    Dim strSQL, strConnect, strSQL2, i

    Dim conn

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\userID\Desktop\My Stuff\MyData.accdb"

    ' Cannot get past this point. It's like I cannot connect to the path above.
    conn.Open strConnect

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO SurveyData (FullName, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Email, Pentium, PentiumMMX, Macintosh, Series486, Series386, Win2000, WinNT, WinXP, WinVista, Win7, Unix, Shopping"

    strSQL2 = ") VALUES ('" & FullName & "', '" & Address & "', '" & City & "', '" & State & "', '" & Zip & "', '" & Phone & "', '" & Email & "', '" & Pent & "', '" & PentMMX & "', '" & Mac & "', '" & PC486 & "', '" & PC386 & "', '" & Win2000 & "', '" & WinNT & "', '" & WinXP & "', '" & WinVista & "', '" & Win7 & "', '" & Unix & "', '" & Shopping & "'"

    ' End the query string
    strSQL = strSQL & strSQL2 & ")"

    ' Send the query to the database
    conn.Execute strSQL

    ' Close the connection to the database
    conn.Close
    strSQL = ""

end sub
```

I have another web site that uses a similar script and that one works. Can anyone see something I'm missing?

Comment: You've got the DB file in your account's home directory. The account that the website (and by extension the vbscript) will running under is HIGHLY unlikely to have access to that directory. Move the DB to somewhere in inet_pub

Comment: @Marc B - Both databases are on my home directory. The other database is a ".mdb" database where the new one is a ".accdb". Could this be the problem?

Comment: mdb is old-school access, accdb is the new xml format introduced in office '07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider works for MDB format database files.  For the newer  ACCDB format (*MyData.accdb*), you need the ACE provider.

For Access 2007, there was only a 32 bit version of the ACE provider.  But starting with Access 2010, there are separate 32 and 64 bit versions.  You need the one which matches the bit mode in which your VBScript runs.

Comment: I'm not using ASP for this client. They are new to the world of internet and have taken the easy path of sending me a WYSIWYG template they want to use. I just had to create the form, the scripts, and add the database.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  What error message do they get from your VBScript now when connecting to the db fails?

Comment: I changed `Jet.OLEDB.4` to `ACE.OLEDB.12` and now it works perfectly!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your connection string to use the ODBC.  Per [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.accdb;
Uid=Admin;Pwd=;
```

Comment: I don't have a username or password for the client because, as much as I suggested they go with one, they wanted to keep it simple. Can I use without?

Comment: You can try Uid=;Pwd=; It has been awhile since I connected to Access via OLE DB or ODBC, but that should work.