# Create Statement to run a Microsoft Access Query using Vbscript

Tags: sql, vbscript

What i have so far is a Query that opens the Microsoft Access Application but i would like to open and run a sql query itself and close the application. the query like

```
SELECT S2iOSGISAcquisitionCSV.Agencia, 
       S2iOSGISAcquisitionCSV.Mercado, 
       S2iOSGISAcquisitionCSV.[Nome Produtor], 
       S2iOSGISAcquisitionCSV.Dispositivo
FROM S2iOSGISAcquisitionCSV;
```

where can i put that statement ? thank you

```
Dim sAcc
    Dim sFrontEnd
    Dim sSec
    Dim sUser
    Dim objShellDb
    Dim sComTxt
    Dim rs

sAcc = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\msaccess.exe"
 '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\msaccess.exe"

sFrontEnd = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TABELA_DE_DADOS.accdb"


Set objShellDb = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Set rs = createObject("SELECT* FROM S2iOSGISAcquisitionCSV");

sComTxt = chr(34) & sAcc & chr(34) &_
      " " & chr(34) & sFrontEnd & chr(34) 
if isNull(sSec)=False AND sSec<>"" Then
    sComTxt = sComTxt & " /wrkgrp " & chr(34) & sSec & chr(34)
End if
if isNull(sUser)=False AND sUser<>"" Then
    sComTxt = sComTxt & " /user " & sUser
End if
 objShellDb.Run sComTxt 
' rs.Run sComTxt
```

Comment: Use an Access provider as your connection string for ADODB. More info [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/). There is no need to open Access, ADODB will execute the query once it has a connection via one if the providers. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262429/why-cant-i-connect-to-my-access-database) might give you a starting point.

Comment: thanks that's good idea connecting using ADODB, but not sure how i put the sql statement after that.